# How to connect hdmi to the television on linux mint cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, hdmi

When I connect to the television via HDMI, all I get on the screen is my desktop background. This is regardless of what is on my laptop screen. I am using Linux Mint cinnamon.

Comment: Clarification: Can you drag a window from your main monitor/laptop screen to this desktop on the TV?

Comment: in terminal type `xrandr` add the output to question (as text).

Answer (score 1):

As patrick points out, the screen is probably added as a second screen and not as a mirror.

Depending on you hardware, it should be anough to go to the "display" settings and choose the "mirror screen" option

Comment: This didn't work the first several times but now it is working.